# How to list dynamic data one below the other in HTML? (MEAN)

Tags: html, css, angular

I get an array of data from the backend and want to display them one below the other via HTML. Is there any way to do this? I have provided my current code below.

TS:

```
 this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
  this.http.get<Organization>('/api/organization/get-details', {
    params: {
      username: params.orgUsername
    }
  })
  .subscribe(organization => {
      this.organization = organization['orgDetail'];
      this.users = organization['usernames'];
```

this.users will contain list of usernames and I want to display it one below another.

HTML code:

```
<span style="display:flex; margin-top: 10px;">
          <mat-icon style="font-size:20px;">person</mat-icon>{{users}}</span>
```

Expected output:

username1

username2
..

Comment: use flex-direction:column.

Comment: Tried it, Not working..!

Comment: Is `users` a string array?

Comment: @Arcteezy Yes, it's string of arrays

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate over the array and display each,

```
<span style="display:flex; margin-top: 10px;" *ngFor="let user of users">
    <mat-icon style="font-size:20px;">person</mat-icon>{{user}}
</span>
```